# Call by Reference Function

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I would just like a push in the right direction here with my homework assignment. Here is the question:

> (1) Write a C function called input which returns void, this
>   function prompts the user for input of
>   two integers followed by a double
>   precision value.  This function reads
>   these values from the keyboard  and
>   finds the product of the two integers
>   entered.  The function uses  call by
>   reference to communicate the values of
>   the three values read  and the product
>   calculated back to the main program. 
>   The main program then  prints the
>   three values read and the product
>   calculated. Provide test results for
>   the input: 3 5 23.5. Do not use arrays
>   or global variables in your program.

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(int *day, int *month, double *k, double *pro);

int main(void){
    int i,j;
    double k, pro;


    input(&i, &j, &k, &pro);
    printf("%f\n", pro);
    return 0;
}

void input(int *i, int *j, double *k, double *pro){

    int x,y;
    double z; 
    double product;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    scanf("%f", &z);


    *pro += (x * y * z);

}
```

I can't figure out how to reference the variables with pointers really, it is just not working out for me.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You adding to `pro` but that is not initialized, you are not passing values back apart from `pro`. You store values into the addresses of variables passed in. In that case you need to dereference pointers to access/retrieve value, `*i`,  and in your method use the passed addresses directly - then you don't need to take address of them again.

This works - I replaced `double` with `float` ... :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input(int *day, int *month, float *k, float *pro);

int main(void){
    int i,j;
    float k, pro;

    i = j = k = pro = 0;

    input(&i, &j, &k, &pro);
    printf("%f\n", pro);
    printf("%d : %d : %f\n", i,j,k);
    return 0;
}

void input(int *i, int *j, float *k, float *pro){

    scanf("%d", i);
    scanf("%d", j);
    scanf("%f", k);

    printf("%d - %d - %f\n", *i,*j,*k);

    *pro += (*i * *j * *k);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3.5
1 - 2 - 3.500000
7.000000
1 : 2 : 3.500000
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, but instead of making new variables `x`, `y`, and `z`, use the pointers you passed:

```
scanf("%d", i);
scanf("%d", j);
scanf("%f", k);

*pro += ((*i) * (*j) * (*k));
```

Comment: Why `+=`? The double has not been initialised, so you'll likely get rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

```
*pro += (x * y * z);
```

This is going to break horribly. You're adding the product to whatever garbage happens to be in pro beforehand. You want to remove the `+`, i.e.:

```
*pro = (x * y * z);
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading the numbers in the `input` function you can make use of the pointers `iptr`, `jptr`, `kptr` and `proptr` to read the values directly into variables `i`,`j` and `k` declared in the `main` function as:

```
void input(int *iptr, int *jptr, double *kptr, double *proptr){

    scanf("%d", iptr); // read directly into i using pointer to i.
    scanf("%d", jptr);
    scanf("%f", kptr);   

    *proptr = ( (*iptr) * (*jptr) ); // compute product and assign to pro.
}
```

Comment: Is it me, or did the question not specify me to do anything with the double value read in?

Comment: @Chad: Thats what I got from the question.

Answer (score 0):

What your program is not doing is setting the values of the input to i, j, and k.

Instead of using x,y and z, use the parameters instead.